# Tkinter app does not respond immediately after execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

tryin to learn python right now. Starting to build some gui's with tkinter. Right now I got the problem that immediately after I run my app, the program does not respond. No errors seen in the ide. I think the problem is somewhere in my function **roll**. Deleting the command paramater from the **rollbtn** allows the gui to run. Any ideas would be appreciated.

With kind regards
DachsAdmin

```
# Author: DachsAdmin
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------packages and variables
from tkinter import *
import random

app = Tk()
app.title("Dice Tool")
app.geometry("600x400+700+300")
app.resizable(width=False, height=False)
#app.iconbitmap("C:\PYTHON\Code\img\dice.ico")


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------functions
def roll(dice_type, dice_quantity):
    dice_result = []
    print(dice_type)
    dice_type = dice_type()[1:]
    dice_type = int(dice_type)
    counter = 0

    while counter != dice_quantity:
        dice_result.append(random.randrange(1, dice_type))
        counter = counter + 1

    for x in dice_result:
        resultbox.insert(END, x + "\n")
    resultbox.pack()


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------coreWindow
frameleft = Frame(app, bg="grey")
frameleft.place(x=10, y=10, width=380, height=380)

resultbox = Text(frameleft)
resultbox.configure(state="disabled")
resultbox.place(x=10, y=10, width=360, height=360)

frameright = Frame(app, bg="grey")
frameright.place(x=410, y=10, width=180, height=380)

variable = StringVar(app)
variable.set("W6")

diceoptionmenu = OptionMenu(frameright, variable, "W3","W4","W6","W8","W10","W12")
diceoptionmenu.place(x=10, y=10, width=75, height=30)

dicequantity = Spinbox(frameright, from_=1, to=99)
dicequantity.place(x=95, y=10, width=75, height=30)

rollbtn = Button(frameright, text="Roll!", width=100, bg="white", command=roll(variable.get, dicequantity.get))
rollbtn.place(x=40, y=300, width=100, height=30)

exitbtn = Button(frameright, text="Exit", width=100, bg="white", command=app.quit)
exitbtn.place(x=40, y=340, width=100, height=30)

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
rollbtn = Button(
  frameright, text="Roll!", width=100, bg="white", 
  command=roll
)
```

and this:

```
def roll():
    dice_type = variable.get()
    dice_quantity = dicequantity.get()
```

---

Ok, sorry did not look further.
Some changes:

```
def roll():
    dice_type = variable.get()
    dice_type = int(dice_type[1:])
    dice_quantity = int(dicequantity.get())
    
    dice_result = []
    for i in range(dice_quantity):
        dice_result.append(random.randrange(1, dice_type))

    for x in dice_result:
        resultbox.insert(END, str(x) + "\n")
```

Remove:

```
resultbox.configure(state="disabled")
```

---

Some clarifications (initially wanted to keep it short:):

This was capturing the functions (function addresses) 'get',
of 'variable' and 'dicequantity':

```
command=roll(variable.get, dicequantity.get)
```

Could solve with a lambda expression:

```
command=lambda: roll(variable.get(), dicequantity.get())
```

For simplicity, just used roll directly + called get() there

```
command=roll
...
def roll():
    ... = variable.get()
    ... = dicequantity.get()
```

About roll() body: The issues were due to type mismatches:
mixing int and string, expecting one but getting the other.
It's easy to get mixed up in a dynamic language.
Hint: to see a variable's type (if not using IDEs etc.),
try using: print(type(variable)).

Finally, disabling the Text widget disallows updates to it.
You may want to start it disabled, enable it before updates,
and disable it again after (to avoid user modifications):

```
def  roll(): 
  ...
  resultbox.configure(state="normal")
  for x in dice_result:
        resultbox.insert(END, str(x) + "\n")
  resultbox.configure(state="disabled")
```

One hint:
Run from command line (e.g. "python3 ./MyScript.py"),
and watch the error messages: they help a lot.

Comment: Yeah after this changes I can run the gui again. But after I press the button same problem. Something is wrong with the while loop. This worked fine as a console only script. Any ideas on that? I want to display the values in **dice_result** to the text box **resultbox**.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. Could you add for the future readers of this anseer: What does your code do and what was the problem in the OPs code?

Comment: Thank you sir this helped alot. I am smarter now! Have a great day an keep up your good work!

Answer (score 0):

Your code got stuck in the `while` loop. This happened because you tried to compare an `integer` to `string`. Also, instead of forwarding a function (`dice_quantity.get, dict_type.get`), I change it for you. I forward the function address and then I called it inside the `roll` function.

```
import random
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Text, StringVar, OptionMenu, Spinbox, Button, END

app = Tk()
app.title("Dice Tool")
app.geometry("600x400+700+300")
app.resizable(width=False, height=False)

def roll(dice_type, dice_quantity):
    dice_result = []
    dice_type = int(dice_type.get()[1:])
    counter = 0

    while counter != int(dice_quantity.get()):
        dice_result.append(random.randrange(1, dice_type))
        counter += 1

    for x in dice_result:
        resultbox.insert(END, x, "\n")
    resultbox.pack()


frameleft = Frame(app, bg="grey")
frameleft.place(x=10, y=10, width=380, height=380)

resultbox = Text(frameleft)
resultbox.configure(state="disabled")
resultbox.place(x=10, y=10, width=360, height=360)

frameright = Frame(app, bg="grey")
frameright.place(x=410, y=10, width=180, height=380)

variable = StringVar(app)
variable.set("W6")

diceoptionmenu = OptionMenu(frameright, variable, "W3","W4","W6","W8","W10","W12")
diceoptionmenu.place(x=10, y=10, width=75, height=30)

dicequantity = Spinbox(frameright, from_=1, to=99)
dicequantity.place(x=95, y=10, width=75, height=30)
rollbtn = Button(frameright, text="Roll!", width=100, bg="white", command=roll(variable, dicequantity))
rollbtn.place(x=40, y=300, width=100, height=30)

exitbtn = Button(frameright, text="Exit", width=100, bg="white", command=app.quit)
exitbtn.place(x=40, y=340, width=100, height=30)

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main issues causing the problem:

- `rollbtn = Button(frameright, text="Roll!", width=100, bg="white", command=roll(variable.get, dicequantity.get))`

  `roll()` function will be executed immediately, not what you expect when the button is clicked.
- `while counter != dice_quantity:` inside `roll()` function. As `dice_quantity` is a reference of `Spinbox.get()`, `counter != dice_quantity` always evaluated as True.  So it is an infinite while loop.

So to fix it:

- Use `lambda` in `command` option: `command=lambda: roll(variable.get(), dicequantity.get())`
- update `roll()`:

```
    def roll(dice_type, dice_quantity):
        print(dice_type, dice_quantity)
        dice_type = int(dice_type[1:])
        resultbox.config(state='normal')
        for i in range(int(dice_quantity)):
            x = random.randrange(1, dice_type)
            resultbox.insert(END, str(x)+'\n')
        resultbox.config(state='disabled')
```